Null or Empty scopes when passed to /oauth2/token giving all the scopes. When scopes are passed, getting proper response
Below is my curl. I am firing /oauth2/token endpoint in my Spring Boot security application. So when I give proper scopes in the request body. I am getting same scopes in response as well as in access_token.
But, the issue is when I don't pass scopes (either null or empty) then I am getting by default all the scopes in response as well as in my access_token JWT.
Curl with scope:
curl --location 'http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=070D5BC0E37818B02C51DC62C7F52EF8' \ --data-urlencode 'client_id=***************' \ --data-urlencode 'client_secret=***************' \ --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \ --data-urlencode 'scope=client.create'

Curl without scope:
curl --location 'http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=070D5BC0E37818B02C51DC62C7F52EF8' \ --data-urlencode 'client_id=***************' \ --data-urlencode 'client_secret=***************' \ --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'

I tried writing manually filter to capture request of /oauth2/token and modified it. But still this solution is not working.
My requirement:
Is there any way to configure to get scopes whatever I pass only. If null scope or empty scope is given in request. Then same should be applied to response and also in my access_token.

The client gets the scopes it requested unless the authorization server restricted the scopes. For other grant types the user could also restrict the scopes. If the client didn't request any scope it get all scopes. What authorization server do you use and how do you registered your client?

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3

If the client omits the scope parameter when requesting
authorization, the authorization server MUST either process the
request using a pre-defined default value or fail the request
indicating an invalid scope.

In your case it depends on the OAuth server. If you have access to server, you should be able to configure or change in code how to respond to empty scopes in request
